# Sharing video with airdrop

Tags: ios, video, avasset, airdrop

I am having some trouble in sharing videos with airdrop. So, i am using the `AssetLibrary` like this :

```
else if (conformsToVideo) {

        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]  initWithTitle:@"Asset Loaded" message:@"Video One Loaded"
        delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];

        self.mediaAsset = [AVAsset assetWithURL:[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL]];

        UIActivityViewController * controller = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:@[self.mediaAsset] applicationActivities:nil];
        [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Maybe this is just not the way to do it, I don't know and I didn't find any tutorial about it so if you have one, I will gladly take it.

Now my problem is that when i select a video everything works fine until the `UIActivityViewController` pops out , i don't have any error but I can't use airdrop (`nor any other service BTW`) the only thing I can do is press the `Cancel button` of the `UIAVController`.

I am using `iOS 8.3`.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, eventually I found an answer, maybe not the best but I put it there in case it helps someone cause I didn't find much on sharing video with airdrop :

```
NSURL * path = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL];
BOOL conformsToVideo = (UTTypeConformsTo((__bridge_retained CFStringRef) mediaType, kUTTypeAudiovisualContent));

if (conformsToVideo) {

            [self.library assetForURL:path
                          resultBlock:^(ALAsset *asset) {
                              ALAssetRepresentation* assetRepresentation = [asset defaultRepresentation];
                              NSString* outputDirectory = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", NSTemporaryDirectory()];
                              NSString* pathToCopy = [outputDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", assetRepresentation.filename]];

                              NSUInteger size = (NSUInteger)assetRepresentation.size;
                              NSMutableData* data = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:size];

                              NSUInteger bytesRead = [assetRepresentation getBytes:data.mutableBytes fromOffset:0 length:size error:nil];
                              NSURL * url = nil;
                              if ([data writeToFile:pathToCopy atomically:YES])
                              {
                                  NSLog(@"Ok");
                                  url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:pathToCopy];
                                  UIActivityViewController * controller = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:@[url] applicationActivities:nil];
                                  [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
                              }
                          } failureBlock:^(NSError *error) {
                              NSLog(@"Failure to use the ALAsset");

                          }
             ];
        }
```

I found the solution using this question : [Share a video from asset library with AirDrop fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23798846/share-a-video-from-asset-library-with-airdrop-fails)
I am merely adding the previous steps to the code given there, hope it can be useful.